# C++ Design pattern for using a abstract class object in another class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, abstract-class

I'm having a class with 2 pure virtual methods and another class which needs to use an object of this class. I want to allow the user of this class to specify which derivation of the abstract class should be used inside of it.
I'm struggling to figure out what the right way is.

```
struct abstract {
    virtual int fst_func() = 0;
    virtual void sec_func(int) = 0;
};

// store an instance of "abstract".
class user_of_abstract
{
private:
    abstract* m_abstract;

public:
    // Pass a pointer to an "abstract" object. The caller takes care of the memory resource.
    user_of_abstract_base(abstract* a) : m_abstract(a) { }

    // Pase any type, which needs to be derived from "abstract" and create a copy. Free memory in destructor.
    template<class abstract_type>
    user_of_abstract_base(abstract_type const& a) : m_abstract(new abstract_type(a)) { }

    // use the stored member to call fst_func.
    int use_fst_func() {
        return this->m_abstract->fst_func();
    }

    // use the stored member to call sec_func.
    void use_sec_func(int x) {
        this->m_abstract->sec_func(x);
    }
};

// use boost::shared_ptr
class user_of_abstract
{
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<abstract> m_abstract;

public:
    // Pass a pointer to an "abstract" object. The caller takes care of the memory resource.
    user_of_abstract_base(boost::shared_ptr<abstract> a) : m_abstract(a) { }

    // use the stored member to call fst_func.
    int use_fst_func() {
        return this->m_abstract->fst_func();
    }

    // use the stored member to call sec_func.
    void use_sec_func(int x) {
        this->m_abstract->sec_func(x);
    }
};

// pass a pointer of an "abstract" object wherever needed.
struct user_of_abstract
{
    // use the passed pointer to an "abstract" object to call fst_func.
    int use_fst_func(abstract* a) {
        return a->fst_func();
    }

    // use the passed pointer to an "abstract" object to call sec_func.
    void use_sec_func(abstract* a, int x) {
        a->sec_func(x);
    }
};
```

It's important to note that parameter "x" from sec_func() needs to be a value returned by fst_func() on the same "abstract" instance.

**EDIT:**
Added another approach using boost::shared_ptr which should take the most advantages.

Comment: I think the name of your second class should be `user_of_abstract_base`.

Comment: Don't forget you need a virtual destructor on `abstract`!

Comment: @Billy | Yeah, thanks for the tip. I've shorten the code to the relevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that passing the `abstract` object into the constructor of your user is the proper approach as the methods of the user depend being called on the same `abstract` object. I would even go further and make the `x` parameter an internal state of your user as you have said it's important that this value is the one returned from a call from the first function.

**Update**: If you are worried about the lifetimes then you could make use of the various smart pointer options available in for example boost. Those should cover most usage scenarios.

Comment: That's correct, but you need to be sure that the passed instance has at least the same life time as the "user_of_abstract" object. That's the only thing I worry about. In addition, it's not that convenient because you need to hold the same instance twice. This isn't straight forward when you don't the "abstract" instance outside of the "user_of_abstract" object. Related to the internal state: Please note my comment on Cem Kalyoncu post.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046 Updated my answer a bit.

Comment: Did you see the update of my initial post? I've already showed a solution with boost::shared_ptr ;)

Comment: @FrEEzE2046 Ah, well that's basically what I meant. Depending on your actual design you might also want to consider `auto_ptr` in case your `abstract` object is created by some kind of factory and you want to pass the ownership to the user class.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say the second function should use the output of the first. I guess first approach will decrease chance of mistakes. You can even modify it to the following:

```
int use_fst_func() {
    return x=this->m_abstract->fst_func();
}

void use_sec_func() {
    this->m_abstract->sec_func(x);
}

protected:
   int x;
```

Comment: I cannot do this, because fst_func and sec_func are called more than once and the result of fst_func is not constantly the same (in fact, it never returns the same number twice). But I'm having a std::set<> to store that informations.

Comment: If you application has no problem with speed you can have another set in this class and if a non-obtain value is submitted you can raise an exception. It will save a lot of debugging time. Also you can put this checking conditional, whenever its in debug mode do it and in release no checks will be performed.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. The std::set I'm using is exactly doing this kind of job. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: What do you think about the boost::shared_ptr approach?

Comment: :( I never got the chance to experiment with boost. But I guess it will be a step up from the regular pointers, assuming it does reference counting for resource management.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting yourself in a sea of maintenance trouble.

**In your first example...**

there's **really** no need for the template constructor. It's speced as

```
// Parse any type, which needs to be derived from "abstract" and create a copy.
```

The **user** can already do that by creating the instance himself and pass it to the first constructor.

Also, with this:

```
// Free memory in destructor.
```

You explicitly say that you have no idea how this class should be used. As your first example is written, you need to decide: use an instance created from the outside or use an instance created on the inside. It's confusing to see an interface with one ctor taking a pointer and another ctor taking a reference, both essentially to the same type.

In my eyes, the only acceptable way of using an instance created from the outside that will  not be memory-managed **or** an instance created from the inside that will be memory-managed, is when there's a default ctor that can initialize the internal pointer to a sensible value (but that doesn't seem to be the case here, since you want to copy another instance):

```
template <typename T>
class user_of_abstract
{
    bool m_owner_;
    abstract* m_abstract;

public:

    user_of_abstract_base(abstract* a = NULL)
    : m_owner(a == NULL)
    , m_abstract(m_owner ? new T(): a)
    {
    }

    ~user_of_abstract_base()
    {
        if (m_owner)
        {
            delete m_abstract;
        }
    }
}
```

**Your second example...**

is superior to the first, since you don't explicitly mix memory management with memory reference. You let `shared_ptr` do it implicitly. Very good, that's what it's for.

However, since you have a requirement that `use_sec_func` must take the output of `use_fst_func` as input, you stay a long way from the safe shore of the sea of maintenance problems.

For instance, what happens if `use_fst_func` on an instance throws an exception and `use_sec_func` is later called on that same instance?

How do you expect that the important information "Always call A before B. And only once. And pass the A result to B." should propagate to users of the class 2 years from now?

Why can't `use_sec_func` just call `use_fst_func`?

**As for your third example...**

can you give 1 single scenario when you'd want to use this instead of just calling the instance functions directly?

Comment: Related to the third example: That's what std::allocator_traits<> (C++0x) does ...

Comment: In addition: You can think of use_fst_func as something that acquires a resource and use_fst_func release it. I think you already nothiced that it wouldn't make any sense to call release(acquire()) or delete new int ...

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: *You can think of use_fst_func as something that acquires a resource and use_fst_func release it* - Oh, God heavens, no! Absolutely not! Where's the exception safety in that?

Comment: This is not my actually code. I've just showed you an example to explain my issue. I'm not sure what exactly you worray about. Where's the exception safety in new/delete? If you don't use new (nothrow), then new can throw std::bad_alloc. Same thing here the first function could raise exactly one specific exception, the second won't raise any exception.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: Exception safety isn't about *not throwing*, it's about what happens to your objects *when* an exception is thrown.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't know what you worry about, when the function doesn't throw an exception. And again: What happens to your objects when new throws an exception? The resource isn't allocated and everything will be reseted when the first function raises an exception.